# Improving UI performance when using Core Data

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, design-patterns, core-data

I've been using Core Data in my project and I've been relying on its data faulting system to return cached data, however I've been running into some performance issues especially when displaying data in a UITableView that configures its view based on this fetched data.

It basically fetches some NSManagedObject instances through their unique ID, and sums up a value stored in an NSNumber. It's doing this for around 40 different objects inside a for loop and it does this every time the UITableView is reloaded.

Is there any suggested way to listen for changes in Core Data NSManagedObjects or a way to cache data at my level, or should I rely on data faulting and it's just that I'm doing something wrong?

If you could point me to a good pattern to handle this situations I'd be immensely thankful.

Comment: Do you have an index on the unique id for the object? It should not take very long to fetch 40 objects that are indexed. Could you post the code where you are handling your core data?

Comment: Sure, I'll add some code in a bit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

NSFetchedResultsController provides a nice mechanism for handling faulting and providing a clean interface with UITableView.  Use Instruments and Time Profiler to get a good picture of where specifically your performance issues lie.

Answer (score 1):

You can retrieve the sum of a property using Core Data directly. Read the section titled [Fetching Specific Values](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/coredata/Articles/cdFetching.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002484-SW1).

This should be the only tip you need:

```
NSExpression *keyPathExpression = [NSExpression expressionForKeyPath:@"Count"];
NSExpression *sumOfCountExpression = [NSExpression expressionForFunction:@"sum:"
                                          arguments:[NSArray arrayWithObject:keyPathExpression]];
```

This should not be slow enough to cause problems, unless you are reloading your table too many times.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you need to do is use NSFetchedResultsController. It is made to work with UITableview, and works very well for what you are trying to accomplish here. Second thing, assign a fetchBatchSize to your fetch request. You don't need to keep all the records on memory.